# Yesod auth route to plugin page interpolation

Tags: authentication, interpolation, yesod, browserid

Is there some value constructor that I can use to interpolate default url of BrowserID's plugin page in pattern `@{AuthR <Cons>}`?

Currently I'm using `@{AuthR $ PluginR "browserid" []}`

---

## Update

Well, now **BrowserId** plugin exposes `forwardUrl` alias which could be used for that purpose (since `v1.3.4`, [commit](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/commit/4fd1f76b1713a62ed047d6667bb366e670d6ef63))

#### A bit of explanations:

I want to use interpolation to render url of default BrowserId auth plugin route where assertion check occurs: `/auth/page/browserid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right thing to do right now. What most of the plugins do is provide a pre-baked `Route Auth` value which is exposed by the module so you don't have to come up with that yourself. We should probably do the same for BrowserId. Would you be able to send a pull request?

Comment: Let me check other modules. I'll try